# Clarification for textbook diagram on electric potential energy and work

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, work

From the textbook I'm reading about the potential energy and work on a positive vs negative charged particle in a uniform E field, for the diagram (b) on the positive charged particle moving from a to b against the E field, since the work is the negative of the change in potential energy which is -qE(b-a), which based on the diagram would give a negative number (so work is negative) since b>a. But for the diagram (a) negative charge moving from a to b, I know work must be negative as well since the negative charge is moving towards the negative plate, but if I calculate the work with -qE(b-a) in this case I would get a positive number since b<a based on the diagram. I photoshopped diagram a (third image) below so that it would make sense to me so now -qE(b-a) would be a negative number. My main question is, is there something wrong with my interpretation? I feel like it's unlikely that the book is wrong and there is just something I'm not understanding.

[image: diagram b]

[image: diagram a]

[image: diagram a that I edited]

Comment: Check your algebra. You've made a sign error - likely omitting the sign of the test charge.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something,  the statement in book diagram b (the second diagram) appears incorrect. Although the potential $U$ increases (since potential is defined in terms of positive charge), the potential energy of the negative charge decreases. Moreover, I think the field does positive not negative work, since the direction of the force exerted by the field is the same as the displacement of the negative charge. Like gravity on a falling object, the field gives the charge kinetic energy while losing potential energy.

Comment: I think g s is right. F should be negative in terms of the negative test charge so F=(-q)E and the work based on the book's diagram (a) would be -(-q)E(b-a) and it would make sense. Also Bob, I think if you look at diagram (a) again based on the book, the bolded red arrow is the force on the negative charge so it would actually be moving opposite direction to the force so it should be negative work.

Comment: @JerryHsieh Ah, when I read your statement "But for the diagram (a) negative charge moving from a to b" I didn't realize they switched labels a and b between diagrams (b) and (a). Poor presentation, in my opinion, as it causes confusion, at least for me.  What adds to the confusion, in my opinion, is they should say that the force actually responsible for the motion of the charge is an external force, not the force of the field. Assuming the charge begins and ends at rest in both diagrams, the positive work done by the external force equals the negative work done by the field.

Answer (score 0):

For the top two digrams assume that $\hat y$ points upwards, $\vec E = E\,\hat y$ so $\vec F = q_0\,\vec E = -q_0\, E\, \hat y$ and the displacement from $a$ to $b$ is $\Delta \vec y = \vec y_{\rm b} - \vec y_{\rm a}= (y_{\rm b} -y_{\rm a})\,\hat y$.

The work done by electric field in moving a charge $q_0$ from $a$ to $b$ is  $\vec F \cdot \Delta \vec y = -q_0\,E\,\Delta y = -q_0\,E\,(y_{\rm b}-y_{\rm a})$

The differences between the two diagrams are the sign of $q_0$ and the relative sizes of $y_{\rm a}$ and $y_{\rm b}$.

**Diagram (a)**
$q_0$ is positive and $y_{\rm b}>y_{\rm a}$, so the work done is
$\,\,-\,\times \;\,q_0 \,\times\: \:E\;\times \:(y_{\rm b}-y_{\rm a})$ and looking at the signs
$[-]\times \,[+]\times [+] \,\times \quad\:[+] \quad\:\Rightarrow [\bf\color{red}-]$ results in a negative quantity for the work done.

**Diagram (b)**
$q_0$ is negative and $y_{\rm b}<y_{\rm a}$, so the work done is
$\,\,-\,\times \;\,q_0 \,\times\: \:E\;\times \:(y_{\rm b}-y_{\rm a})$ and looking at the signs
$[-]\times \,[-]\times [+] \,\times \quad\:[-] \quad\:\Rightarrow [\bf\color{red}-]$ again results in a negative quantity for the work done.